# Disable CORS in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, post, cross-domain

I have two nodeJS/express applications. For simplicity, I'll say one is hosted on www.example1.com and the other is hosted on www.example2.com. I want to send a POST request from www.example2.com to wwww.example1.com. I do this with the following code:

```
<form action="www.example1.com" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

I only want this to accept requests from www.example1.com. How do I do this? Also, currently, when I do this post request, the POST request is actually going through. I don't understand why. Are there no default settings to prevent against the cross domain requests? How can I put up these settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the cors middleware package is the standard way to do this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

e.g:

```
const allowedOrigins = ['www.example1.com', 'www.example2.com'];
app.use(cors({
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    if (!origin) {
      return callback(null, true);
    }

    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
      const msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not allow access from the specified Origin.';
      return callback(new Error(msg), false);
    }
    return callback(null, true);
  }

}));
```

Comment: I am using csurf and cookie-parser, but only want to exclude the example2.com from fulfilling this requirement